# kErrno 2 No such file or directory: '~/Users/root1/Coursera DeepLearning/Course2/dogs-vs-cats/train' - But it EXISTS

Tags: python-3.x

```
import os
import zipfile
train_dir = '/Users/root1/Coursera DeepLearning/Course2/dogs-vs-cats/train'
os.getcwd()

[output]'/Users/root1/Documents/Coursera DeepLearning/Course2'

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(train_dir,
                                                    batch_size=20,
                                                   class_mode='binary',
                                                    target_size=(150, 150))  

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/root1/Coursera DeepLearning/Course2/dogs-vs-cats/train
```

The directory exists and contains subfolders train and test

Answer (score 0):

yet I can't figure out how your project layout looks like but since the error indicates a path issue I'd suggest you adapt this code to your needs if it doesn't work the way I wrote it.

```py
PATH = os.getcwd()
DATASET = os.path.join(PATH, "dogs-vs-cats")
```